# How to update my feed's favicon in Google Reader?

Tags: rss, feed, atom-feed, google-reader

Today I launched my new website with new design and with a new favicon. I used the same URL for my RSS feed in order to keep my subscribers.

But Google Reader retains the old favicon. How can I force it to update it?

Comment: If you hard refresh your browser, will it update or stay the same?

Comment: Stays the same, everywhere. The same favicon stays even in Webmaster Tools.